# css3 box-shadow https vs http

Tags: css, http, https

I ran across something peculiar today regarding inset box-shadows and https vs http.

Using Chrome (Version 37.0.2062.120 m), if I do an inset box-shadow on an img, it works just fine so long as that img's URL is http (example: http://somebodyelseswebsite.com/myimage.png). If that image is using https (example: https://thisotherguyswebsite.com/hisimage.png), the inset drop-shadow will not show up.

Is it a security issue or perhaps a bug/oversight by Google? Anyone have any thoughts?

```
<img style="width:150px; box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 5px #000" src="https://kfscdn.api.np.km.playstation.net/64924751177e14943eec338b1f02cb08a838321c2ed38d0dc546622311399dc5/48b8a11c7d5f31a1efd874e197d0e1b9/1410306322100.png"></img>
<br>
<img style="width:150px; box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 5px #000" src="http://static-resource.np.community.playstation.net/avatar/default/DefaultAvatar.png"></img>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9TMdc/4/

Comment: Please note that I am also seeing this in FireFox. IE11 seems to have a weird border bug when viewing the HTTPS

Comment: The drop-shadow is actually there, but the image refuses to let the drop-shadow be on top of it in this particular instance. I put a drop-shadow on the container div and the issue still persists.

Comment: Is this image called from an http and/or httpS page? Did you test with another value than `inset`? I saw demos of ASCII-art entirely done with multiple box-shadows so *if* it can also be done with `inset`, one could completely *deface* an image coming from a "secure" site (or at least could be visually modified) so yeah a security issue would be a reasonable explanation

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot I got the answer to your question below but I have the doubt if you still want to make it appear the box-shadow inset in your image with background color white. I can help you with that if you want it or it was just that you wanted to know why it happened?

Comment: @ShazboticusSShazbot I just updated my answer inclyding a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Http or Https is not the problem, see this:

http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/9TMdc/6/

I am calling it the two ways:

```
<img style="width:150px; box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 5px #000" src="http://static-resource.np.community.playstation.net/avatar/default/DefaultAvatar.png"></img>

<img style="width:150px; box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 5px #000" src="https://static-resource.np.community.playstation.net/avatar/default/DefaultAvatar.png"></img>
```

Http and Https the same image and I see the box-shadow. The problem is that the first image have white background and the second image has background transparent. So you see the box-shadow in the second image but not in the first one because of the white background.

See that the first image I called it the two ways Http and Https, in the first one with `box-shadow: inset` and the second one not inset and it worked fine. You just dont see the inset shadow because of the white background of the image.

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/9TMdc/9/

I set a background-color in a `div` containing your images so you can see the background of your images. The first one has a background color white and the second one is transparent. Remember that in PNG images you can have transparent background colors while in JPEG images you can't.

**UPDATE**

http://jsfiddle.net/carloscalla/9TMdc/10/

I included a workaround to set the `box-shadow: inset` in your image with background color different than transparent. I wrapped it in a `div` and set the `z-index: -1` to your image so the `div` comes in front. Notice that `position: relative` is important because `z-index` property only applies to positioned elements, that means `relative`, `absolute` and `fixed`. Does not apply to `static` elements (which comes by default).

Comment: Original fiddle from OP with some background color different from white: http://jsfiddle.net/9TMdc/7/ so the transparency is more obvious

Comment: Thanks haha I was editing my answer to include that so he can see it better.